# addthis.js not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, addthis, socialshare, add-this-event

when i am trying to show the social share links using `addthis.js` its showing nothing as an empty div is being appended. can someone please help me out in fixing this issue.

the script i am using is ::

and i am trying to show the the links through a javascript div.

```
result = result +' <div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox"></div>';
result = result +'  <div class="clear"></div>';
result = result +'  </div>';
result = result +'  <div class="jobApply"><a title="Create Alert" href="javascript:void(0)" class="alertBtn" onClick="alertFunction();createAlert(\''+requirements.requirementUUID+'\');"><i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i></a>';
result = result +'   <a onClick="applyJob(\''+requirements.requirementUUID+'\');">Apply</a>';
result = result +'  <a href="/login" style="background-color:#eb821c;">Refer</a></div>';
result = result +'  </div>';
result = result +'  </div>';
```

Comment: Do you have this line of code `addthis.init();`? Call it after the document has finished loading.

Comment: Why are you doing so much HTML in JavaScript...? Can you not reference the HTML content in JS by setting IDs etc?